# Delphi Android long process waiting message

Tags: android, delphi, mobile

In my Android application with a button, I start an SQL query. This query runs long (about 1-3 minutes) and I would like to show a waiting message to the user.

This waiting message is done via a `TRectangle` with a label inside. The rectangle is not visible until the button is pressed:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Rct1.Visible := True;// Make message visible .....
  RunSql; // Sql query 
end;
```

Procedure `RunSql` executes an SQL request and updates the UI to show the data in 12 `TEdit` components.

The message is showed (the rectangle is visible) AFTER `RunSql` ends. But I need to show it before `Runsql` is called.

Run step by step in IDE:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Rct1.Visible := True;// Now the rectangle must show, but is not visible
  RunSql; // go to this procedure and execute sql 
end;      // Here after 1-3 minutes I have all the components updated with the sql result and show the message.
```

How can I show the "waiting" message at a right time?

Window 7/10 (ide)
Android 9 (Samsung S10)
Delphi 10.3.3

Comment: Could you be more clear about where Android fits into this, please?

Comment: @IvanWooll Because, Delphi on Android is a bit different than Delphi on Windows and while there are common solutions that can be used on both platforms, Windows specific solution will not work on Android.

Comment: I am assuming that your SQL query is running in main thread, otherwise rectangle would show when you need it. You should move running query to background thread not only to solve GUI issue, but also because Android will kill your application if you are doing too much work in main thread.

Comment: I suppose you use FireDAC. How about [Asynchronous Execution](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Asynchronous_Execution_(FireDAC)) then?

Comment: @Dalija Yes it runs in main thread. The program has only one form with 1 button and 12 tedit.  The button runs the sql procedure. Next approach is run sql in another task. i'll try. The post was bad formatted. i'm very sorry please excuse me.